# jQuery datatable serverside html response

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

The scenario

I need to create a data-table with full functionality (pagination/filtering/etc). The data is sent from the server over AJAX (50 rows at a time)

I am already using jquery-datatables plugin but since there isnt a clean implementation for such use case I am stuck

```
<tr>
<td>col 1</td>
<td>col 2</td>
<td>col 3</td>
<td>col 4</td>
</tr>
```

So I need to create a dataTable with say 5 pages (10 rows each page) and then say when user is on page 5, append the next 5 pages and have the next paginatio buttons show up...

Any help is hugely appreciated

Comment: you can use datatables plugin https://datatables.net/

Comment: I am using tht... was wondering how I can achieve this functionality with it since it does now have direct support for it.

Comment: yes it supports AJAX, you will find better anwers if you post what you have tried

Comment: doesnt it only support JSON formats for AJAX.... is it possible for you to point me to an example where HTML response is involved?